# android: map not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm trying to show a mapview inside a fragment. The map view never shows. WHat am I missing?

```
public class FriendsGroupMapFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

View friendsGroupMapFragmentView;
GoogleMap friendsMap;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public FriendsGroupMapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Log.d("ON CREATEVIEW()","ON CREATEVIEW()");
    friendsGroupMapFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends_group_map, container, false);
    drawMap();

    return friendsGroupMapFragmentView;
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    drawMap();
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    //public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

public void drawMap(){

    Log.d("drawMap","drawMap");
    if(friendsMap != null){
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        friendsMap = ((MapView)friendsGroupMapFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.mapfriends)).getMap();
        if(friendsMap == null){
            Log.d("NULL","NULL");
        }

        LatLng chennai = new LatLng(13.0839,80.2700);
        friendsMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(chennai));
    }

}

}
```

my xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.mobile.activity.FriendsGroupMapFragment">



<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapfriends"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.mobile.activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.test.mobile.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my_apikey_value"/>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml and your manifest?

Comment: Don't know if you have posted your code without the api key, but make sure that you have your api key instead of my_apikey_value.

Comment: Yeah. I have the api key. i just didn't add here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `drawMap`:

```
public void drawMap(){

    Log.d("drawMap","drawMap");
    if(friendsMap != null){
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        friendsMap = ((MapView)friendsGroupMapFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.mapfriends)).getMap();
        if(friendsMap == null){
            Log.d("NULL","NULL");
        }

        LatLng chennai = new LatLng(13.0839,80.2700);
        friendsMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(chennai));
    }
}
```

You are creating map here only when it is already created :)
Try to change to

```
if(friendsMap == null)
{
    ....
}
```

**EDIT**

I completely missed that you use `MapView` instead of MapFragment.

With `MapView` you need to pass all the fragment lifecycle events (`onCreate`, `onDestroy`, `onResume`, etc) to your `MapView`. See [this section of docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html)

The only thing I would mention is that since you inflate `MapView` inside fragment, you need to call `MapView`'s `onCreate` inside `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Log.d("ON CREATEVIEW()","ON CREATEVIEW()");
    friendsGroupMapFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends_group_map, container, false);
    this.mapView = (MapView)friendsGroupMapFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.mapfriends);
    this.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawMap();

    return friendsGroupMapFragmentView;
}


@Override
public View onResume() {
    this.mapView.onResume();
    .....
}
```

And so on

Comment: Yeah. I changed it and now i get NPE. getMap() is null

Comment: Also is it a better way to have mapfragment inside my fragment instead of mapview?

Comment: That's the only way to get `MapView` working - to call lifecycle events manually :). Actually documentation says you should do that. With `MapFragment` - it is just easier - you don't need to worry about lifecycle - it does everything for you. So it is up to you which way to choose. The problem with nested fragments is that they were introduced in API 16, so if you want to use MapFragment inside another fragment and your min SDK is <16 - you have to use fragments from support lib

Comment: Ok.. Thank you :) I changed MapView to SupportMapFragment :)